# Automapper -AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-4

I trying out Automapper, with a really easy mapping, but it does not work.
I am trying to map a `System.Security.Claims.Claim` type to another type ClaimItem:

```
public class ClaimItem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

But I always get:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Claim -> ClaimItem System.Security.Claims.Claim ->
>   CommonAuth.ClaimItem
>
> Destination path: ClaimItem
>
> Source value:
>   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/dateofbirth:
>   05.05.2016

Here is my configuration:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Claim, ClaimItem>(MemberList.Destination);
});

config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var cls = getClaims();
List<ClaimItem> list = new List<ClaimItem>();
cls.ForEach(cl => list.Add(Mapper.Map<ClaimItem>(cl)));
```

Comment: There must be text explanation what is wrong. Can you provide all text

Comment: Updated! :-) In my destination type I have only two props, Type and Value, I want these two properties to be mapped from the sourceType Claims.
They have the same names in source and destination.

Comment: Where you get Mapper? because it should injected in version 4

Comment: This is just a Unit test, where I run the code for testing. I thought Mapper is a wrapper, which has a reference to the config, right???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API) you must create mapper from config. So you should have in your code smth like this

```
 private static Mapper _mapper;
    public static Mapper Mapper
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mapper == null)
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Claim, ClaimItem>(MemberList.Destination);
                });

                config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
                _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            }
            return _mapper;
        }
    }
```

This means that if you have static **Mapper** it hould be created from config which you create

Comment: Now it works, So, I have to create a singleton in order to access "mapper", right?

Comment: @Legends i have update my answer. So it depends. You could use singleton or you could have factory class which will create mapper.